# Service Mediation Using Proxy Services -WSO2

Tags: web-services, wso2, mediator, wso2-esb

I'm new to this area and i need to access my web service via the ESB. as it mentioned in here - [Service Mediation Using Proxy Services](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Quick+Start+Guide) i tried to to create it. after that i run it and get the response as follows :

```
<TryitProxyError xmlns:h="http://wso2.org/ns/TryitProxy"
h:status="SOAP envelope error">org.apache.axis2.AxisFault:
The input stream for an incoming message is null.</TryitProxyError>
```

but i tried to run same web method using **SOAPUi** and get the expected out put as below:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <getPatientHistoryResponse xmlns="http://tilani.lk/">
         <getPatientHistoryResult>
            <NIC>123</NIC>
            <FullName>ABC DEF</FullName>
            <FirstName>ABC</FirstName>
            <Surname>DEF</Surname>
            <Title>Mr.</Title>
            <Gender>M/Gender>
         </getPatientHistoryResult>
      </getPatientHistoryResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

what is the reason for this? i created this using .net

my **WSDL Address** - `http://localhost:2935/PatientRegService.asmx?WSDL`

then in 
**Define Endpoint** as - `http://localhost:2935/PatientRegService.asmx`

**EDIT**
my proxy configuration is as follows:

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="PatientManagement" transports="https,http" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
      <endpoint>
         <address uri="http://localhost:2935/PatientRegService.asmx?WSDL"/>
      </endpoint>
   </target>
   <publishWSDL uri="http://localhost:2935/PatientRegService.asmx?WSDL"/>
   <description></description>
</proxy>
```

Comment: what is your proxy configuration?

Comment: @Ratha - i'm totally new to this area and i tried custome proxy as mentioned http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Quick+Start+Guide in here and then tried with pass through proxy as mentioned by maninda.. but still couldn't able to configure it.

Comment: Can you give your passthrough proxy conf(ie: synapse configuration) added a sample conf ..check that and see whetehr you are getting response or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to access your web service via ESB you need to create a proxy service and access the proxy service URI instead of the original service URI. Just follow the [Pass Through Proxy example](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Pass+Through+Proxy+Template).

Comment: in the above example if we select Target Endpoint as Enter URL do we need to give WSDL path for that? for the above my scenario do i need to give `http://localhost:2935/PatientRegService.asmx?WSDL`

Comment: i tried as mentioned the link. but still gives me same error msg.

Comment: In pass through proxy, only endpoint URL should be given. For example try with the http endpoint URL in the echo service hosted in default in the ESB itself.

Comment: thanx maninda.. i'm able to configure esb. i forgot to host web service in iis. that is the reason for gave me this error. i'm able to connect it using pass through proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following proxy and see waht you are getting. Add this proxy configuration via source view editor.

```
 <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
           name="testProxy"
           transports="https http"
           startOnLoad="true"
           trace="disable">
       <description/>
       <target>
          <inSequence>

             <log level="full">
                <property name="testprop" value="incoming message"/>

             </log>

             <send>
                <endpoint>
                   <address uri="http://localhost:2935/PatientRegService.asmx"/>
                </endpoint>
             </send>
          </inSequence>
          <outSequence>
             <send/>
          </outSequence>
       </target>
    </proxy>
```

Comment: i tried this one and select endpoint as `PatientManagementHttpEndpoint` then it gives same message -`The input stream for an incoming message is null. `(Private proxy protocol will be attempted as cross-domain browser restrictions might be enforced for this endpoint.)

Comment: when i tried with `PatientManagementHttpSoap11Endpoint` it gives following error `<faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
   <faultstring>System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: urn:mediate.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.Soap11ServerProtocolHelper.RouteRequest() at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.RouteRequest(SoapServerMessage message)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create `

Comment: If you notice the above proxy configuration we haven't added a wsdl to that.SO, if you check the WSDL of the proxy , it is a default wsdl and it is not related to your backend service. What you have to do is, create a soapui project with your actual backend service WSDL and send that request to this proxy. Proxy will route taht request to backend service.

Comment: i'm able to configure esb. i forgot to host web service in IIS. that is the reason for gave me this error. i'm able to connect it using pass through proxy. anyway thanx for ur help.